# can azure worker role call dnn stored procedure

Tags: azure, dotnetnuke

I am wondering if I can insert some data into a Dotnetnuke DB from a Azure worker process. What i need to do is create a user in DNN, so would be inserting into 2 tables on DNN.

So, How do I connect? 
Is it possible?
Any sample code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... a *worker process* runs in a Windows Server virtual machine. You would just need to connect to the database and call the appropriate stored procedure (or execute the appropriate T-SQL) just like you would in any other app. You'll just need a connection string with proper credentials.

Keep in mind: All instances of a Worker Role have the exact same code deployed. If you're trying to do some type of background processing that results in a database call, just make sure that call is only done once (maybe by using Azure Queues to write a request for creating a user, then having all the worker instances read from the queue, and the one who gets the message then creates the new account).